# How to convert the list user enter ed names in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Im new to numpy and having trouble converting the list of names to numpy array. can anyone please help me, ill really appreciate it

```
  nameList = []
  maxListLength = 5
  while len(nameList)<=(maxListLength):
     userEnteredNames = input("Enter a name please:")
     if not userEnteredNames.split():
        print("Name cannot be blank, Try Again")
     elif userEnteredNames in nameList:
        print("You already entered that name")
     else:
        nameList.append(userEnteredNames)
        print(nameList)
```

Comment: just use `numpy.array()`, like `nlist_array = np.array(nlist_list)`

Comment: I tired but then it interferes with the .append method its giving me error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: numpy has `np.append()`, you can refer to [this site](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

Comment: There is 'num' in `numpy`, which means this package is designed for numerical processing. You can of course use it with strings, but there is typically no good reason to do so. So why do you want to use numpy in the first place? If you really want numpy, then use `nlist_array = np.array(nlist_list)` as suggested by @ToughMind, but after the `while` loop is over. Using `np.append` at every iteration should be less efficient...

Comment: Just convert it to an array *after* you're done appending stuff to the list.